# Furigana not served on my Desktop, have to get it to go (mobile)

Tags: bug, design, responsive-design, preferences

On our [Anime](https://anime.stackexchange.com/) and [Japanese](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange sites we have support for [Furigana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furigana).

In the Desktop View the settings dialog and the link to it isn't accessible (I also checked my Profile Settings and the Top Bar Menu for an alternative (Desktop) way to access the settings, without success). You can only see the access link in mobile mode, if you notice it in the footer.

In addition the text extends outside the dialog box.

If you could see the activation link and the settings dialog it looks like this:

[image: Furigana Settings Dialog]

In addition to these two sites there might be other sites affected, where there's an additional custom settings dialog not visible in Desktop viewing mode. I've checked several seemingly likely candidates but so far I only see this issue on these two sites.

Comment: I would expect thus to be available under your profile > settings. But it isn't....